# Folder access rights DMS

Tags: java, authentication, architecture, file-permissions

I'm developing an application which copy PDF files to server. My swing application scan and label the documents which are scanned then copy to server. There are two roles  doctypesA read and write,doctypesB read and write. I stored roles in database and handle this rights from my swing application. When user use my application there isn't any problem because ı can control, total 200 users approx.  But my problem is that anyone who knows the link on server   SEVER\MYDOCS\doctypesa\doc.pdf  can see it. It is intranet application, how can i restrict folder in this situtation.

MY APP JAVA SWING, INTRANET

Answer (score 0):

I consider to solve this problem, ı'll use encrypt/ decrypt my pdf files.